# Поддержка Google Play

Tags: google-play

Примерно месяца два назад зарегистрировал аккаунт разработчика Google Play, выслал документы без всяких бликов. Через несколько дней пришло сообщение типа "Не удалось вас опознать. вы истратили все попытки (хотя была одна), напишите нам для возврата денег". Написал как полагается. Прошёл месяц. Тишина. Хорошо, написал ещё раз. Уже неделю тихо.

Сколько там ждать вообще нужно?

Comment: знакомый разработчик сильно ругается, что последнее время с этим бардак и ждать приходится долго

Comment: может подождать, а может забудут, вот apple иногда (по себе знаю), может неделями не отвечать пока по телефону не позвонишь и не спросишь в чём дело, большие конторы по мере увеличения переходят на совецкие принципы хозяйствования

Comment: ответили. спустя 4 месяца.

Answer (score 0):

Желательно предоставить внятные фото паспорта и прописки без засветов и заломов, желательно загран.

Оплачивать сбор с личной карты оформленной на вас и в дальнейшем которая будет использоваться для вывода денег.

Регистрация обычно проходит за сутки если нет ошибок или неточностей в заполнении

Comment: регистрация то была, проблема только в том, что деньги  за сбор возвращать не хотят.

Comment: Странно что не хотят. Должны вернуть на ту карту с которой была сделана оплата. Нужно внимательно посмотреть на письма которые они присылали все это время, возможно там где-то ссылка на подтверждение.

Comment: уже три письма им отправил - абсолютно никаких ответов.